# Relationship between vector's length and scalar multiplication

Tags: vectors

The question is:

> Find vector's $(1, 1)$ length, if scalar multiplication $(v, u)$ is
>
> 1. $(v, u) = ((x_1, y_1),(x_2, y_2)) = x_1\cdot x_2 + y_1\cdot y_2$
> 2. $(v, u) = ((x_1, y_1),(x_2, y_2)) = (x_1 + y_1)\cdot(x_2 + y_2)$

How vector's length even related to the scalar multiplication?
Thanks

Comment: @Riddleoo The question posed seems not clear to me, could you check again the original question?

Comment: The length of $v$ is $\sqrt{(v,v)}$.

Comment: Form in 2. is degenerate, if $v=(x,-x)$, then $(v,u) = 0$, for all $u$. Thus, it is not scalar multiplication and doesn't define norm (length). It does define seminorm, though.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

By "scalar multiplication" this question means "dot product," as in "the multiplication of two vectors which produces the scalar". You then can use the formula $\|u\| = \sqrt{(u,u)}$ to get the length of a vector $u$

Comment: Thank you. Now I understand it.

Answer (score 1):

Every *inner product* (also known as scalar multiplication) induces a so called *norm* which expresses the 'length' of a vector, with respect to the given inner product.

Specifically, the norm is defined by $\ \|v\|^2=\langle v,v\rangle$.

Equipping a vector space with an inner product basically amounts to introducing a notion of *length* and a notion of *enclosed angles* for the vectors.

Comment: Thank you for your response, it is now clear to me